# How to fetch the stock market details in an android application

Tags: android, html

We have developed an android application based on html5.
We need to fetch stock exchange, currency and commodity details(gold, silver etc) here from the corresponding websites and also we need to store these details in the database (SQLite).
Please provide the solution for doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Connect to the Stock market API if one exists.

Comment: This is just a minor re-phrasing of your earlier question, which was closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is going to get closed because it's not a programming question and it's entirely vague.

However, in broad non programming strokes, your solution is to do as follows:

If you're building an HTML5 app it doesn't matter if it's Android based or not. It's a web app.  You're going to get a stock feed of some kind (what feed were you planning on using? does it have an API to fetch data?) and you will write some sort of server side fetcher to get the data and collect it via AJAX, and display it in a browser. Then you'll embed a WebView in an Activity and point it at this web app.